# Solr facet query not working as expected

Tags: solr, filter, facet

In my application I am using multiple fields for faceting.
For e.g. two fields are used for faceting say 'gender' and 'apparel'
gender is having below values
 - men
 - women
 - kids
apparel is having below values
 - shirt
 - trouser
 - skirt
 - leggings
 - shorts

I am using facet query to filter the results to retain the facets 
so when i try facet.query=gender:men in the results its returning all the facet values for apparel, whereas I am expecting only shirt and trouser to come in the facet result.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to restrict by *gender:men*? Then, that should go into *fq* (filter query) and you should get the results you expect.

As is, the various facet queries are independent from each other and one will not have the effect on another. They are just counts.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. Is there anyway to implement this?

Comment: Implement what? Restriction like I said just need to go into the filter query instead of the facet. Maybe review the tutorial that ships with the Solr in the docs directory. I think it explains some of these concepts.